# R - Join tables from within loop to table outside of loop

Tags: r, for-loop, join

I've done something similar by binding tables together that are generated in a loop, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to truly JOIN them between the loops.

I have nested loops. The first loop iterates through a list of file locations and seeks out a specific file to gather summary data. Once the data is gathered and formatted, it looks like this:

**Table1**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1
root    home    Sample1     1    1
root    home    Sample1     2    0
root    home    Sample1     5    1
root    home    Sample1     7    1
root    home    Sample2     1    0
root    home    Sample2     2    1
root    home    Sample2     3    1
root    home    Sample2     4    1
root    home    Sample3     1    0
root    home    Sample3     3    1
root    home    Sample3     6    1
```

Next, a new loop starts that iterates through specific files in the directory corresponding to each sample name. This creates a table specific to the individual sample that looks like:

**Table2**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name  ID  Value2
root    home    Sample1    1   5000
root    home    Sample1    2   9000
root    home    Sample1    5   400
root    home    Sample1    7   3500
```

What I am trying to figure out is how do I JOIN the second table to the first table based on the File_Name and ID columns? That way as the second loop runs, it populates a Value2 column in the first table linked to the corresponding File and ID?

**Intermediate Output:** (updated Table1 in the main loop)

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1   Value2
root    home    Sample1     1    1        5000
root    home    Sample1     2    0        9000
root    home    Sample1     5    1        400
root    home    Sample1     7    1        3500
root    home    Sample2     1    0        
root    home    Sample2     2    1        
root    home    Sample2     3    1        
root    home    Sample2     4    1       
root    home    Sample3     1    0       
root    home    Sample3     3    1        
root    home    Sample3     6    1
```

**The basics of my current code:**

```
for (i in first_list){
master list = tibble(file = i) %>%
    mutate(Data = lapply(file, function(i){
    read.csv(i, header=TRUE, skip=1, sep = "\t", check.names = "FALSE")})) %>%
    unnest(Data)


     second=list.files(path=raw_file_path,recursive=T,pattern=raw_data,full.names=T)

     for (i in second_list){

        sub_list= tibble(file = i) %>%
        mutate(Data = lapply(file, function(i){
        fread(i, sep = "\t", select = c(10,19),skip=1)})) %>%
        unnest(Data)

    }
#push data to database before beginning next loop iteration
}
```

The ultimate desired outcome after the second loop runs through each file in it's list would be:

**Output:**

```
Path1   Path2   File_Name   ID   Value1   Value2
root    home    Sample1     1    1        5000
root    home    Sample1     2    0        9000
root    home    Sample1     5    1        400
root    home    Sample1     7    1        3500
root    home    Sample2     1    0        5646
root    home    Sample2     2    1        5999
root    home    Sample2     3    1        10000
root    home    Sample2     4    1        42
root    home    Sample3     1    0        655
root    home    Sample3     3    1        12358
root    home    Sample3     6    1        6800
```

Comment: Not sure how you get the final output but the intermediate output is a simple `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)` (or in base R: `merge(df1, df2, all.x = T)`). How are the remaining values for `Value2` generated?

Comment: Not sure why you need to loop. Might need to see underlying loop data to know how final output is rendered.

Comment: @MauritsEvers The second loop imports the next file of data, which corresponds to a different sample on the list. So it's joining another chunk of data each time it loops. I also forgot that the second loop introduces data that doesn't exist in the first table.  Currently seeing if it's as simple as calling a merge before the second loop recycles.

Comment: @Parfait Most likely because I don't know the proper way to do it in R. I'm used to looping through file lists, so that's just how I have it set up.